# Google distancematrix API without a key

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I have a python script to calculate driving distance between two points.  Here's  my API call.  I did not use any API Key.

```
urlGoogle = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + origZip + "&destinations=" + destZip + "&mode=driving&units=imperial&language=en-EN"
```

Once while testing with lots of data I got an error for exceeding the limit.  My question is how does Google track/monitor my usage without a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your server's ip address.  Which could be problematic if you are on a shared server.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip.  This is a good answer.  I believe for server side call using Google API key or Client ID for work is the way to go.

Comment: @geocodezip what if we call the api from mobile device which mostly be on different network. Will it work without any api key? Daily 10 times per on each device.

Comment: @ik024 I think so.